# ACSD-51892: Performance issue where config files load multiple times

Tags: magento2, error, configuration, patches, performance

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-33/acsd-51892-performance-issue-where-config-files-load-multiple-times.html?lang=en
I tried to reproduce error to check how this patch work. But unfortunately I can't reproduce this error. Could someone explain to me the way we reproduce this error. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Github issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37435 and the Github pull request https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/37436#issuecomment-1588058995

The issue is the `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig::reloadData()` has been called  many times, which cause a significant increase of the CPU usage and negatively impact the performance: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php

To verify that, you can utilize the logging feature to add a log in the `reloadData` method in the `\Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig` class to monitor the number of the calls made before and after applying the patch.

Note: this issue has been fixed in the Magento 2.4.6-p2, which was released last week.